# Изменение стиля элемента

Tags: winapi, c++

Есть у меня группенбокс, на котором располагаются три кнопочки. При нажатии на одну из них это группенбокс должен  стать невидимым. Попробовал  SetWindowLong, но не получается. Может она вообще не в тему (английский не знаю, поэтому недопонимаю англоязычные ресурсы). В общем вопрос: как изменять стили элементов?  При нажатии на кнопочку всё окно зависает, хотя если убрать SetWindowLong и оставить MessageBox, то всё нормально. Где мог напортачить?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GrpBoxWndProc(HWND hGroupMainMenu, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LONG style;
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if(wParam == BM_NEWGAME){

            MessageBox(NULL,_T("DFGGDF") ,   _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),  NULL);
            style = GetWindowLong(hGroupMainMenu,GWL_STYLE);
            style = style = style || WS_BORDER ;
            SetWindowLong(hGroupMainMenu,GWL_STYLE,style);
        }
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hGroupMainMenu, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Плох тот программист, который не знает английского...

Comment: не спорю... это мешает быстрому росту

Comment: Всё, кажется понял! Это общемировая проблема перерисовки Group box.

Comment: Если что, "группенбокс" я тогда написал исключительно ради петросянства, а так он groupbox :-) А стиль по-моему нужно WS_VISIBLE сбрасывать.

Comment: Я раньше тоже любил смотреть выступления Г.В. Петросяна, и посему поддержал. А что до Visible, то оно да, но в моём случае изучения этих вещей даже применеие линии оборачивается непонятками.

Answer (score 1):

1. После выполнуния строки

   style = style = style || WS_BORDER ;

переменная style будет содержать 1, т.к. выполняется не побитовое сложение '|', а логическое ('||').

1. Для чего выполнять 2 присваивания??

Comment: Понимаю непонимание, это потому что я еще сам не всё понимаю, а такое понимание в моё понимание привнёс один из наgoooogleнных примеров примеров.

Comment: Решил не взрывать мозг таким количеством слова "понимание"))

Если нужно удалить флаг WS_BORDER, то нужно писать:

style &= ~WS_BORDER;